# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive][c++]

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am fairly new to c++ and prcticing some ds algo problem. From last 24 hours, I have been stuck with this.

```
/*Find shortest distance of every cell from landmine in a maze*/

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <climits>

struct cell{
    int x, y;

};

const int M = 6, N = 5;

int row[4] = {-1, 0, 1, 0};
int col[4] = {0, -1, 0, 1};

bool isValidandSafeObject(int x, int y, char mat[][N], int minDist[][N]){
    if ((x >= 0 && x < M) && (y >= 0 && y < N) ){
        if  (mat[x][y] == "O") && (minDist[x][y] == -1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int[][N] updateDistance( char field[][N]){

    int minDist[M][N];
    queue<cell> Q;

    for (int i = 0; i < M ; i++){
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if (field[i][j] == "M"){
                Q.push({i, j})
                minDist[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else{
                minDist[i][j] = -1;
            }

        }
    }

    while (!Q.empty()){
        int x = Q.front().x;
        int y = Q.front().y;

        Q.pop();



    for( int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
            i = x + row[k];
            j = y + col[k];

            if isValidandSafeObject( i, j, field, minDist){
                Q.push({i, j});
                minDist[i][j] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

return minDist;
}

void main(){
    char mat[][N] =
    {
        {'O', 'M', 'O', 'O', 'X'},
        {'O', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'M'},
        {'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'},
        {'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O'},
        {'O', 'O', 'M', 'O', 'O'},
        {'O', 'X', 'X', 'M', 'O'}
    };
    int minDist[M][N];


    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << updateDistance(mat);;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }


}
```

At line 20, `if  (mat[x][y] == "O") && (minDist[x][y] == -1){`

I am getting the error `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]`. I have searched stackoverflow, but none of the existing problems and solutions, seem to satisfy my problem.

I am using CodeBlocks.
It would be very helpful, If someone could help me.

Comment: Unlike Python, there's a huge difference between `"0"`and `'0'` in C++.

Comment: You should better use `std::vector` instead of plain C-arrays. If you have a C++ book that advises you to use plain C-arrays in situations as above then *get a new book*!

Comment: `updateDistance` returns a pointer to an object with automatic storage, which will lead to undefined behaviour if you try to access it. You probably want to check out the [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: "ISO C++ forbids comparison" is the smallest of the problems of this code. There is a bunch of syntax errors. The main problem is that you cannot return a C-style array from a function.

Comment: @dtell agreed, I can't believe my school still teaches C++ with a book that promotes char arrays, `using namespace std`, turbo C++ and also has no idea what the STL library is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `'X' vs "X"`

C++ doesn't treat these two the same way. 
`'X'` is treated as a `char` in C++.

But the second you use `""`, the meaning changes. Now it is treated as a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Or, a **sequence of characters**. Or, a `char[]`.

```cpp
char c = 'X'; 
char c = "X"; // how dare you
```

## How pointers?

Back to our example, to make it clear, when I said `""` implies a string literal or a sequence of characters, so when you do

```cpp
char c = "x";
```

You are assigning a **sequence of characters**, to a `char`. It is equivalent to doing

```cpp
char c = "Hello, World!"
```

So how does a [pointer](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_pointers.asp) come in here? If you don't know anything at all about pointers, this will be a bit difficult to understand.

Pointers are just addresses. I could create a pointer and give it the adress of anything at all, an `int`,  `char`, `double`.. doesn't matter, it's just gonna hold the memory address of that object. 
In the same way, a `char*` would point to something that can be interpreted as a `char`.

```cpp
int a = 5;
int ptr_to_a = &a; // ptr_t_a now holds the address of a
```

But there's something strange, take this code for example

```cpp
const char* str = "foo"; // valid!
```

If pointers store addresses, how can it store a sequence of characters? C++ will secretly, or implicitly convert the following code into this.

```cpp
char sequence[] = {'f','o','o'};
```

And after this, it will return the address of the first element, which is `f`, and assign it to the variable `str`. So now `str` points to the first element, in a character array.
Hence you can assume that it will treat `"foo"` as a pointer. And since `""` is implies a string literal, in your case it treats `"O"` as a pointer.

So we you do `mat[x][y] == "O"`, you are comparing `int == char*`.
Therefore, `mat[x][y] == "o"[0]` will work because now you will access the first element of the array you just constructed.

### Solution

The solution is to use `''` instead.

```cpp
if (mat[x][y] == 'O') //...
```

---

Also refer to [this](http://iso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-intege) post, though it is the C language, the concept is the same.

Answer (score -1):

Characters in double quotes represent a pointer to a zero-end string of these characters ,no matter what the number of the characters is.

So "O" is not a char.It is a pointer to a zero-ended string.

'O' is a char.

Comment: `"O"` is not a pointer. It's a string literal. Its type is array of chars, i.e. `const char[2]`. Arrays in some contexts decay to pointer, but an array is not a pointer.

Comment: @bolov It is again something really confusing in C++, especially to beginners who break their heads learning pointers and then see `const char* = "Hello world"`